# How to listen the load event of specific layer on Cesium

Tags: cesiumjs, terrain

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67883291/14326456, I am now able to know when tiles on globe are loaded. However, I would like to know if there is a way to listen loading event on a specific imageryLayer ? And not on all at the same time.

```
viewer.scene.globe.tileLoadProgressEvent.addEventListener(function (queuedTileCount) {
    console.log(queuedTileCount);
    console.log(viewer.scene.globe.tilesLoaded);
    if(viewer.scene.globe.tilesLoaded){
        // doSomething
    }
});
```

Comment: CesiumJs does not support functions you want

Answer (score 0):

i don't think this is good idea but i had no choice but to use `setInterval` like this to know when `tilesLoaded` is True.  
Tell me if there is better way. Thanks.

```
setInterval(() => {
    if(viewer.scene.globe.tilesLoaded){
        // viewer's been fully loaded
        // do what you want
        // .... 



        clearInterval(interval) // clearing setInterval
    }
}, 100)
```